# Is the compass app required to take location permission from the user?

Tags: ios, cllocationmanager

My application has a compass feature. For getting heading we used

```
func locationManager(CLLocationManager, didUpdateHeading: CLHeading)
```

Method.
Should I need to take location permission from the user?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this

```
func requestLocationPermission() {
    let manager = CLLocationManager()

    manager.delegate = self
    manager.startUpdatingHeading()
    // Store manager variable
}
```

And implement

```
func locationManager(_ manager: CLLocationManager, didUpdateHeading newHeading: CLHeading)
```

Update: You can observe updating heading without location permission.

Comment: Thanks for reply. I have already added keys in info.plist and request permission too. My confusion is,. Can we use above heading method without taking permissions?

Comment: @SangramShivankar Yes, You can get updating heading without permission.